# Multiple MySQL DB connections in PHP good or bad practise?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, performance-testing, database-performance

I want to add a new discussion area to my website in which users will be able to add topics and receive comments.

I thought I will add a new DB just for the topics and comments to avoid my main DB becoming very large.

But, I will need to connect to the main DB to retrieve user information, perform login processes and so on.

So, what should be better for my site's performance? and why?

1- Adding new tables in my main DB for topics and comments.

2- Adding a new DB just for the topics and make 2 DB connections.

**Note:** Please, focus on the general idea of the question not only this specific case.

Comment: Just create another table. That's it.

Comment: If you want to know what has a better performance, just test it. And what is the practical use of a second DB?

Comment: Do you mean new Table?

Comment: I know it is easier to just add new tables but I'm concerned about the total size of the database

Comment: Why is this neg voted? I find this question pretty useful indeed. So much neg aura around SOF :/

Comment: You could also put the 2nd DB on a 2nd server, to spread the load. Or start a 2nd web site whose sole purpose it to comment on the first. (wink. Just joshing, unless your visors, comments, etc are hitting 7 or 8 figures, you will never notice a performance issue)

Comment: @Mawg I hope I can do that but I can't afford another server. LOL :D

Comment: Not even with the advertising revenue from those millions of commenters? Btw, I up-voted the question - it is perfectly cromulent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the tables to the same database.

The `topics` and `comments` tables have a relationship to your existing data (especially your `users` table, since you probably want to store which user started a topic or wrote a comment), and should therefor be in the same database.

You might even want to enforce the [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) of your database by making sure that every `author_id` in your `topics` and `comments` tables exists as a `user_id` in your `users` table. You can enforce this using [foreign key constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) but, as far as I know, only if all tables are in the same database.

Answer (score 5):

I would say option 1.

It keeps your code more organized and your site doesn't have to load in and retrieve data from a second database. it's also easier to connect which user posted what. Large database shouldn't matter as long as you write your query in a proper way.